# SharePoint Online создание резервной копии сайта

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

**Дано:** Около 15 сайтов на SharePoint Online.

**Задача:** Периодическое создание резервных копий всего содержимого (контента) сайта: *библиотеки документов* - копирование в какое-либо резервное локальное хранилище; *списки* - экспорт в excel, архивирование и также копирование в хранилище.

Вариант реализации: например, на PowerShell или C#.

Проблема возникает на этапе получения контента сайта. Если бы SharePoint был установлен локально, то проблем нет (например, из того же C# можно использовать объект SPSite), да и если бы он был локально, то проблемы резервирования вообще не было бы.

**Вопрос:** как, используя PowerShell или C#, получить содержимое сайта (библиотеки, списка), расположенного на SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с SPO вас потребуется [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=35585). После этого можно начинать работать с SPO, [пример](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105653/retrieve-all-site-collections) получения контекста, и печать всех свойств сайта:

```
siteUrl = "https://yourtenantname-admin.sharepoint.com";
userName = "you@company.com";
password = "password";

using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, passWord);

    var tenant = new Tenant(clientContext);
    SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable spp = tenant.GetSiteProperties(0, true);

    clientContext.Load(spp);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (SiteProperties sp in spp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sp.Title);
    }
}
```

[Тут множество примеров](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx) работы с контекстом SPO. В общем задача думаю реализуема, нужно просто немного покопаться с SDK и майкрософтовских доках.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую использовать этот SDK. О результатах отпишусь, чтобы остальные знали, работают ли эти методы.